# Column mismatch writing a Python Pandas data frame to csv in unix vs windows

Tags: python, unix, csv, pandas

I have created a python pandas data frame object and now I am trying to write it out to csv.  The following command will work in Windows, but when I run the exact same code on the exact same data in Unix, the column headers do not align with the columns after writing out to csv.  The df looks fine within Python when I am running it from he command line (ie, df["somecolumn"] shows me what I would expect).  Any ideas?

```
df.to_csv(str(outfile), sep=",", header=True, index=False, na_rep="NA", cols=firstcols)
```

EDIT:  Here is a look at my inputs which I would lie to merge by the first column "VAR":

```
> more infile*
::::::::::::::
infile1.tsv
::::::::::::::
VAR     CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     P       IPU     IRF     IUC     IGN
1:12892:TGG:T   1       12892   TGG     T       0.1383  .       intergenic      ncRNA   NONE(dist=NONE)
1:14397:CTGT:C  1       14397   CTGT    C       0.5863  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   WASH7P
1:17084:GGT:G   1       17084   GGT     G       0.2337  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   WASH7P
1:17421:ATG:A   1       17421   ATG     A       0.1089  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   WASH7P
::::::::::::::
infile2.tsv
::::::::::::::
VAR     CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     P       IPU     IRF     IUC     IGN
1:14567:G:GAT   1       14567   G       GAT     0.1299  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   WASH7P
1:14670:TG:T    1       14670   TG      T       0.1319  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   WASH7P
1:14745:GGC:G   1       14745   GGC     G       0.1462  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   WASH7P
1:14905:GA:G    1       14905   GA      G       0.1307  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   WASH7P
::::::::::::::
infile3.tsv
::::::::::::::
VAR     CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     AC      AF      PU      RFG     GI
21:10862612:G:A 21      10862612 G      A       3       0.00            intergenic      NONE(dist=NONE),NONE(dist=NONE),TEKT4P2(dist=894019),TPTE(dist=44131),AK311573(dist=265170),TPTE(dist=44131),ENSG00000169861
21:10862618:T:C 21      10862618 T      C       14183   0.65            intergenic      NONE(dist=NONE),NONE(dist=NONE),TEKT4P2(dist=894025),TPTE(dist=44125),AK311573(dist=265176),TPTE(dist=44125),ENSG00000169861
21:10862623:T:C 21      10862623 T      C       1       0.00            intergenic      NONE(dist=NONE),NONE(dist=NONE),TEKT4P2(dist=894030),TPTE(dist=44120),AK311573(dist=265181),TPTE(dist=44120),ENSG00000169861:ENST0000030209
```

And here is my python script

```
import csv
import pandas
import glob
from glob import iglob

inpath = '*.tsv'
outfile ="merged.out"

merged = pandas.concat([pandas.read_csv(f, sep='\t', parse_dates=False) for f in glob.iglob(inpath)], axis=0)

dfcols = merged.columns.tolist()
firstcols = ['VAR', 'CHROM', 'POS', 'REF', 'ALT'] #preserve order of first 5 columns only

for d in set(dfcols):
    if d not in firstcols:
        firstcols.append(d)

merged.to_csv(str(outfile), sep="\t", header=True, index=False, na_rep="NA", cols=firstcols)
```

Here is some of what the truncated output looks like to illustrate how the headers do not match:

```
> more merged.out 
VAR     CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     AC      AF      IUC     PU      P       RFG     IRF     IPU     IGN     GI
NA      NA      T       1       NA      NONE(dist=NONE) .       intergenic      ncRNA   0.1383  12892   NA      TGG     NA      1:12892:TGG:T
NA      NA      C       1       NA      WASH7P  .       ncRNA   ncRNA   0.5863  14397   NA      CTGT    NA      1:14397:CTGT:C
```

However, the columns looks like they are annotated correctly within the Python environment?  I am stumped

```
>>> merged['VAR']
0      1:12892:TGG:T
1     1:14397:CTGT:C
2      1:17084:GGT:G
3      1:17421:ATG:A
0      1:14567:G:GAT
1       1:14670:TG:T
2      1:14745:GGC:G
3       1:14905:GA:G
0    21:10862612:G:A
1    21:10862618:T:C
2    21:10862623:T:C
3    21:10862624:G:T
```

Comment: what if you open it from an Excel-like program? Do the columns align then?

Comment: Still out of order.  It will preserve the order if I run it from Windows, but not if run from the cmd line